# Hyperledger Composer - Angular App Compile

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I spun up an Ubuntu server on AWS and everything is working as expected with Hyperledger Composer except when I try to compile an angular-app using "npm start" after creating the app via "yo hyperledger-composer:angular". Its taking forever to compile at 92% chunk asset optimization. When I do the same exact steps on my local mac laptop, no issues at all. Must be some sort of version issue with something in the node_modules? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

probably because your AWS VM instance is behind a proxy - ie its network interface doesn't know how to route to www and specifically to https://registry.npmjs.org/ for example as its trying to install packages when you do an `npm install`

Comment: I can install packages no problem using npm install. The 92% issue goes away if I do "ng serve --host ***.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 4200 --sourcemap=false"  but then when I go into the angular app I see "Error: 404 - Could not find API route. Please check your available APIs."